# Php Mysqli query no returning any value or error

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to create an order tracking system and has the following query

```
    //create the order variable and assign it the value that the user has entered
            $order = $_POST["order"];
$query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT shipping_status FROM orders WHERE code_ticket = $order");
  if($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
//the status value
     $status = $result['shipping_status'];
  }
  else{
    $status = "Order Not yet placed";
  }
```

My problem is that the query is that I am getting the else part executed and not the if part even when I supply a value that is in the db.
What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: try with ' ".$order." '  instead of $order and also check with == in if statement

Comment: echo - "SELECT shipping_status FROM orders WHERE code_ticket = $order" and run manually to check the result

Comment: use a prepared statement to avoid sql injection

Comment: @Altmish-E-Azam the query is returning zero all the time

Comment: @user3782114  in this case OP is assigning the associative array to the uninitialised variable $result. On failure mysqli_fetch_assoc returns False, (so $result is False) else it returns an array which evaluates to True.

Comment: @Otema then it will execute else condition. echo $query ; and share the complete query

Comment: @Altmish-E-Azam this is the error `There is an error with db:Unknown column 'T' in 'where clause'`

Comment: change your code like--
$order = $_POST["order"];
$qry="SELECT shipping_status FROM orders WHERE code_ticket ='". $order."'";
$query = mysqli_query($link,$qry);

Comment: I have this data `T-51643` to check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are developing this system it would be sensible to adopt best practises earlier rather than later - in this instance I refer to `sql injection` and alas the above code is vulnerable. My guess with the above is the lack of quotes around the embedded variable - `code_ticket = $order` ~ if `$order` is a string then it needs quotes. That said it is very easy to inject this with nastiness so a `prepared statement` would be the way forward. I quickly rewrote your code to show how you might use both a `try/catch` block and a `prepared statement` to hopefully resolve the problem and make the code more secure going forward.

```
<?php

    if( $link && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST["order"] ) ){
        try{

            $order = $_POST['order'];

            /* basic query with placeholder for variable */
            $sql = 'select `shipping_status` from `orders` where `code_ticket` = ?';

            /* create the prepared statement object */
            $stmt = $link->prepare( $sql );

            /* if the query failed raise an exception to indicate failure */
            if( !$stmt ) throw new Exception( 'Failed to prepare sql' );

            /* so far so good. Bind placeholder to a variable */
            $stmt->bind_param( 's', $order );

            /* execute the query */
            $result = $stmt->execute();

            /* deal with recordset */
            if( !$result ) throw new Exception( 'No results: Order not placed' );
            else {

                /* bind column data to an output variable */
                $stmt->bind_result( $status );

                /* fetch the records */
                $stmt->fetch();

                /* do something with output variable */
                printf( 'Shipping Status: %s', $status );


                $stmt->free_result();
                $stmt->close();

            }
        }catch( Exception $e ){
            exit( $e->getMessage() );
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks this is a new field but your explanation has enlightened me and I will adopt it but my problem is actually with the data inputed `T-123456`

Comment: Is it possible to write a query with that? directly on mysql it is executing but not in php

Comment: ? `Is it possible to write a query with that?` ~ please explain.

Comment: My db has data in this format `T-81593`

Comment: And I would like to query it but I get the error `There is an error with db:Unknown column 'T' in 'where clause'` when I execute the query from php but none when I rewrite the query in mysql

Comment: ok - so `T-81593` is a column in a db table? Use backticks around the column - though ideally you would never use a `-` character instead an underscore `_` is preferred. If you use backticks it should be ok

Answer (score 0):

Check if `$query` is equal to `false`. If it is, then use `mysqli_error()` for checking the error:

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, "YOUR SQL QUERY");
if(!$query) {
    echo "There is an error with db:" . mysqli_error($link);
    exit;
}

//continue your code
```